# Ansys AEDT and Icepak Simulation

Tags: rf, antenna, coax, waveguide

I have designed slotted coax cable based waveguide and FR4 is not getting any heat and even the coaxial cable does not get any heat which I do not understand why. E field as follows, ports include 2kW power.

[image]